# How do I assign the parent in a child of a 1:many relationship in Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Here are the relevant classes where an Event and User object has a collection of Signup objects.

```
public class Signup
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }

    public required User User { get; set; }

    public required Event Event { get; set; }

    //  more properties...
}

public class Event
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }

    public ICollection<Signup> Signups { get; set; }

    // more properties ...
}

public class User
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }

    public ICollection<Signup> Signups { get; set; }

    // more properties ...
}
```

So when I create a Signup, I am assigning the appropriate User and Event to it.

```
var builder = CreateBuilder();
using (var context = new LouisHoweDbContext(builder.Options))
{
    var user = context.Users.First(u => u.Name == "Dave1");
    var campaign = context.Campaigns.First(c => c.Name == "Campaign1");
    var evnt = context.Events.First(e => e.Campaign == campaign);
    var signup = new Signup()
    {
        User = user,
        Event = evnt
    };
    context.Signups.Add(signup);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

And it blows up with the below exception. Clearly it's unhappy that Event and User have a PK - but they should have a PK as they're existing DB entries I'm tying to this new entry.

How am I supposed to assign this for the relationship?

```
    Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException : An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details.
---- Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Events' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.
Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Users' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.
```

**Update:**

Found the cause of the problem. It's having NoTracking set.

```
        private static DbContextOptionsBuilder<LouisHoweDbContext> CreateBuilder()
        {
            var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<LouisHoweDbContext>();
                builder.UseSqlServer(DbConnectionString);
//                  .EnableSensitiveDataLogging()
//                  .UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking);
            return builder;
        }
```

turn that off and it works. Why???

**Update 2:**

Ok, so the problem is turning of tracking. That brings up two questions.

Question 1: Most of what I've read (not all) says for an ASP.NET Core app, turn off change tracking. It's unnecessary overhead for any read-only pages which is a lot (not all) of a website. Is that correct? Or should I have change tracking on? Or should I have two DbContext objects, one with change tracking off?

```
context.Users.Attach(user);
context.Events.Attach(evnt);
context.Signups.Add(signup);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Question 2: If the answer is change tracking off, how do I perform the above code correctly?

Comment: When you load an entity without tracking, EF is populating the entity class but retains no knowledge that the entity represents an existing row. If you associate that detached entity to a new Signup and tell EF to add that signup, EF by default treats that new signup and any related entities as New unless those related entities are tracked. Hence the error, When given a reference to an untracked entity EF will treat it as a new record. The alternative if you must use the No Tracking behaviour is to Attach the User and Event to the DbContext prior to saving the new Signup.

Comment: @StevePy I updated the question based on your reply. I would appreciate your thoughts on if an ASP.NET Core app should run with change tracking off. As for attach, I assume that just means add the two Attach calls. TIA

Comment: The best answer I can give is to leave change tracking on, and to leverage Projection (`Select` and Automapper with it's `ProjectTo`) for read operations to populate view models for read purposes. Projecttion does not result in entities being tracked and optimizes reads for just the data that is necessary. Loading the entity (and relatives) itself only happens during updates, and this is typically done by PK which is about as fast as a persistent system can be,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have should work. Ensure that that user wasn't already in the DbContext change tracker in the Added state, for some reason.

The most likely cause of this error is that you had change tracking disabled, and when you added the Signup, the User and Event got added as well.

You can also fix this by setting the foreign key properties (or shadow properties) on Signup instead of setting Navigation Properties to the entity references.

So either turn on change tracking or Attach the User and Event entities so they are Unchanged instead of Added.

Here's a working sample:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;


using var db = new Db();
db.Database.EnsureDeleted();
db.Database.EnsureCreated();


using (var context = new Db())
{
    var u = new User();
    var e = new Event();
    db.Users.Add(u);
    db.Events.Add(e);
    db.SaveChanges();

}

using (var context = new Db())
{
    var user = context.Users.First();
    var evnt = context.Events.First();

    var signup = new Signup()
    {
        User = user,
        Event = evnt
    };
    context.Signups.Add(signup);
    context.SaveChanges();
}

Console.WriteLine("Finished");


class Db : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users{ get; set; }
  
    public DbSet<Event> Events { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Signup> Signups { get; set; }
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=(LocalDb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=EfCore7Test;TrustServerCertificate=true;Integrated Security=true",
            o =>
            {
                o.UseRelationalNulls();
            }).LogTo(m => Console.WriteLine(m));

        optionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging();
        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    }


}

public class Signup
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }

    public required User User { get; set; }

    public required Event Event { get; set; }

    //  more properties...
}

public class Event
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }

    public ICollection<Signup> Signups { get; set; }

    // more properties ...
}

public class User
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }

    public ICollection<Signup> Signups { get; set; }

    // more properties ...
}
```

Comment: What is the call modelBuilder.Entity<Signup>(); doing? I added that - still fails.

Comment: Prior to calling this code I did something similar to what you have adding a bunch of entries. That's all in a using DbContext with a context.SaveChanges() at the end. And the records are in the database. So how do I track down why it's unhappy - with both exiting objects?

Comment: 1) Nothing, I took it out.  2) Use a new DbContext or clear the change tracker.

Comment: Looking at DbContext.ChangeTracker.StateManager.Entities, it has 0 entries before calling Signups.Add(), then 3 entries after calling it. Doesn't the 0 before mean it's not tracking any change from the user & evnt objects? This is really weird. And all three entries have "Added".

Comment: I found it - I have UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking) set. I commented that out and it works. (Your example helped - I kept searching for a difference.) Now the question is why is that a problem...

Comment: It's not a problem.  Don't do that; or add the User and Event to the DbContext as Unchanged, so it doesn't try to insert them.

Comment: But I'm not adding them - I'm merely calling Find() to retrieve them. I'm writing unit tests to match what will happen in my web app and it'll be exactly this, retrieve the two objects to assign to the new object I'm going to add to the DB. How can I do that? TIA

Comment: When you Add the Signup you also Add the related entities.  They weren't already in the change tracker, so they're treated as new entities.

Comment: Ok, getting this figured out. And thank you for your help to this point - wouldn't be this far without you. But giant question, that I added in my original post now - should I turn change tracking off? Also, if you update your answer to say turn change tracking on OR Attach() to objects then I'm happy to accept it. TIA